# 534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections

Tags: windows, security, ftp, ssl, iis

I am trying to configure a test FTP site via IIS 6.2 on a Windows Server 2012 R2

I created a site and configure the FTP SSL settings. I selected my certificate and choose custom.

If I don't have the settings I can connect properly but with this configured I am having an error stated below

```
Response:  220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:   AUTH TLS
Response:  534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
Command:   AUTH SSL
Response:  534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
```

I am wondering if this is due to a server or in the configuration of my IIS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure SSL is enabled also in IIS root configuration, not just in site configuration.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/6122b960-cbf8-4c8e-b432-e973dac6eb1a